# Execute custom javascript function on refresh button click in of Kendo upload control

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have been using the Kendo Upload control, in one of my project.

Once I hit the upload in, upload file popup, if there is any error the upload panel stay there. We display error message in another flyout which stays there for around 30 seconds.

When there is an error, there is no more upload button avaibale, in upload file popup, but we have refresh button.

What I want to do is, I want to execute a jquery function which can hide the error message.

How can I get access to refresh button event, as I do not see any event of refresh button in kendo upload.

We are using kendo mvc wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hitting on refresh button should call your upload event.

What you can do is register for the upload event as below:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload().Name("uploadFile")                              
   .Events(e =>
    {                                   
      e.Upload("onUpload");
    })
```

You can have then onUpload javascript function and hide your error flyout.
Note that above function will also get called on upload buttton click.